# quoted string not properly terminated in plsql block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have table ot.config as:
[image]

I have table ot.stu as:

[image]

I have plsql block as:

```
declare
vquery long;
cursor c1 is
select * from ot.config1;
begin
for i in c1
loop
vquery :='INSERT INTO all_acc_num(code,nbr_value) 
select '''||i.acct_nbr||''','||i.acct_nbr||' from ot.stu';
commit;
execute immediate vquery;
end loop;

end;
/
```

But,when I compile I got error as:

```
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
ORA-06512: at line 10
```

How to handle this error?

My expected output is:
[image]

Comment: is i.acct_nbr a string or a number?

Comment: i.acct_nbr is a string

Comment: I don't have your table, so I used `SCOTT.EMP` instead. The block compiled fine, not sure why you get that error. With that said: (1) Don't use the `long` data type; use `clob` instead. (It will work with `long`, it's just a very bad practice). (2) What is the point of committing **before** your inserts? Perhaps you have your reasons, but that looks odd. (3) `commit` in a procedure (rather than outside it) is generally a bad practice anyway.

Comment: Uhm... I see, you edited the question, and now it makes sense. The issue is caused by the single-quotes in the content of your table. Use the Q-quote mechanism for your SQL string.

Comment: @mathguy maybe 32K is OK. Personally I quite like the PL/SQL `long` (not the obsolete SQL `long` of course).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - 32K is OK (maybe) for what? Not sure what that is in reference to. Then - why do you like the PL/SQL `long`, over `clob`?

Comment: @mathguy apologies for vague drive-by comment. I was referring to "(1) don’t use the `long` data type". If the SQL text is not expected to exceed 32K I don’t see anything wrong with it. I suppose I always have a suspicion that a `clob` variable involves more moving parts and resources, but of course I have no proof of that.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - I see. I just checked the "bible" of PL/SQL (Steven Feuerstein's book) - I didn't know that in PL/SQL the `long` data type is limited to 32,760 bytes. So - as he says in the book - why would anyone **ever** use `long` over `varchar2` (never mind `clob`)? In the book, he advises strongly against using `long` in PL/SQL specifically.

Comment: Well, I could type `varchar2(32760)` or I could use the predefined subtype. (To be honest I was sure it was defined in `standard` or `dbms_standard` but it seems it is not, or not any more in 19c.) SF and the Oracle manuals routinely advise against `long` as a matter of policy, I think, because obviously the SQL one is horrible and obsolete. But just because the 'maximum length varchar2' subtype happens to be called 'long' I don't see why it should be tarred with the same brush. (I expect I am about to be told off for chatting in comments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle apostrophes in `acct_nbr`, use `replace()`. Also you need to add alias `a` for `ot.stu`, because you use `a.name` in regex.

```
declare
  vquery varchar2(32767);
  cursor c1 is select * from config1;
begin
  for i in c1 loop
    vquery :='INSERT INTO all_acc_num(code,nbr_value) 
              select '''||replace(i.acct_nbr, '''', '''''')||''', '||i.acct_nbr||' from ot.stu a';
    dbms_output.put_line(vquery);
    -- execute immediate vquery;
  end loop;
end;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e366a75b9daad1ed163dd6237665b7d2)</sup>**

Use `dbms_output` to see if your code produces valid sql. Once it is OK comment `dbms_output` and uncomment `execute immediate`.

Comment: No... don't use REPLACE. Use the Q quoting syntax for the SQL string!

Comment: what is the replace function actually doing here? it was the same output i was expecting

Comment: @mathguy Don't do that either; use bind parameters.

Comment: @MT0 This. We have some hundred-lines long dynamic sql queries that use tens of (usually optional) bind parameters. I don't want to image how hard it would be to debug possible errors if we had all of them concatenated directly into query. 

So, get used to get practices even if you have just two variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value using a bind parameter when you want to use it as a literal value and use string concatenation when you want to use it to dynamically generate a column name.

So if your tables are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE config1 ( acct_nbr, table_name ) AS
SELECT 'REGEXP_REPLACE(a.name,''/*/'')', 'abc' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE stu ( name ) AS
SELECT 'as' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cc' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE all_acc_num( code VARCHAR2(50), nbr_value VARCHAR2(20) );
```

Then your anonymous block could pass the literal value with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... USING ...`. Also, if your identifier is `a.name` then you also need to define the alias `a`:

```sql
DECLARE
  vquery CLOB;
  cursor c1 is
    select * from config1;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN c1 LOOP
    vquery :='INSERT INTO all_acc_num(code,nbr_value) 
select :1,'||i.acct_nbr||' from stu a';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( vquery );
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vquery USING i.acct_nbr;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> INSERT INTO all_acc_num(code,nbr_value) 
> select :1,REGEXP_REPLACE(a.name,'/*/') from stu a
> ```

and:

```sql
SELECT * FROM all_acc_num;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CODE                         | NBR_VALUE
> :--------------------------- | :--------
> REGEXP_REPLACE(a.name,'/*/') | as       
> REGEXP_REPLACE(a.name,'/*/') | bb       
> REGEXP_REPLACE(a.name,'/*/') | cc
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=be0d8a809ab6cfecd44cee792b0c1bce)*

Comment: Won't work if `acct_nbr` strings have embedded single-quotes, will it? That's what is causing the OP's issues to begin with; not cured by this solution, I think.

Comment: @mathguy Fixed.

Comment: why did you use :1 there?